# how to use setLayout for JLayeredPane in netbeans drag&drop?

Tags: swing, netbeans-7, jlayeredpane

i try to use JLayeredPane with netbeans drag&drop

i need to setLayout & setLayer of it(in design view)

but i can't find setLayout

if i write setLayout manually(in source view),

it will no effect in design view

(i need the effect in design view to make me more simple)

can i do this?
how?

thanks a lot for any kind of help

EDIT :

for example i want to create a button like in microsoft office 2007.. (it located in corner (northwest)) the button located between toolbar and something(container maybe).. so i think i must use layeredpane to make component can in front of each other.. and it will more helpfull if i can use netbeans drag&drop(in design view) with setLayout effect of JLayeredPane.. (i just want to make many component can in front of each other with gridbaglayout) (just try to create cute UI)

Comment: don't understand what exactly your problem could be - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you want to achieve and/or how it behaves differently from your expectation

Comment: Why are you trying to set a layout manager on a `JLayeredPane`?  The purpose of the `JLayeredPane` is to allow you to get away (more or less) without one?  If you want to do "page flipping" (ie have the ability to move between different views, but have only one visible at a time), use a `JPanel` and a `CardLayout`

Comment: @kleopatra just need a way to do setLayout of JLayeredPane in netbeans GUI builder/drag&drop(design view)... by default netbeans can't do that..

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks.. but i don't need CardLayout this time.. i edit my question with an example..

Comment: thanks for the clarification - can't help, though, never used a builder (except my own :-)

Comment: @kleopatra if its private builder?!?! if not can i know it? hehe ^.~